# Need help in passing JavaScript array to my php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to transfer javascript array to my php file? I saw in the internet that I can do it using AJAX however I'm just thinking if there is easier way to do it. Please check my code below:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h3>SCENARIO</h3><select name="SCENARIO" type ="text" id = "SCENARIO">
 <option value="WEBSERVER">WEBSERVER</option>
 <option value="APPLICATION">APPLICATION</option>
 </select>
 <h3>DESCRIPTION</h3><input type="text" name="DESCRIPTION" 
id="DESCRIPTION" placeholder ="Check - Status - HTTPD PROCESS">
<h3>COMMAND</h3><input type="text" name="COMMAND" id="COMMAND" 
 placeholder ="./ops_script/check_RPA/check_HTTPD.sh

<button onclick="getTextBoxValues2();">Add</button>


 <table id="taskTable" border="1">
 <tr>
 <th>SCENARIO</th>
 <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
 <th>COMMAND</th>
 </tr>
 </table>

 <button onclick="delete();">Delete</button>


 <script type ="text/javascript">

 function getTextBoxValues2()
 scenario = document.getElementById("SCENARIO").value;
 description = document.getElementById("DESCRIPTION").value;
 command = document.getElementById("COMMAND").value;

 var tasktable = document.getElementById("taskTable");
 var tasktableArray = tasktable.length;
 var row = tasktable.insertRow(tasktableArray);

 var cell_0 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell_1 = row.insertCell(1);
 var cell_2 = row.insertCell(2);

 cell_0.innerHTML = scenario;
 cell_1.innerHTML = description;
 cell_2.innerHTML = command;

 var x = document.getElementById("taskTable");
 var taskDefinitionArray = [];

 for (var r = 1, n = x.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
 for (var c= 1, m = x.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++){

 taskDefinitionArray.push(x.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
 }
 }                    
    }
        }


  </script>
  <script>
   function delete(){
   var rowCount = taskTable.rows.length;
   for (var i =rowCount -1; i >0; i--){
   taskTable.deleteRow(i);
    }


    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My goal is to transfer the array variable named taskDefinitionArray to my php file named  InsertManual.php. In this scenario I have two function named getTextBoxValues2 and delete. Please let me know if you know a simple way to transfer it to a php file thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `AJAX,`
Convert js array in json format by `JSON.stringify()`

```
function ProcessAJAXRequest()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myphpfile.php",
        data: {"myJSArray" : JSON.stringify(myArray)},
        success: function (data) 
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And In the PHP use `json_decode()` function to get value in array

```
json_decode($_POST["myJSArray"]);
```

Comment: Or just pass the array as `... data: {"myJSArray": myArray}`. jQuery will do the work for you. In PHP it would just be `$arr = $_POST['myJSArray'];`

Comment: Hi I tried the ajax its returning this values: 
localhost:8001 says

<html>

<body>

</body>

</html>

I don't understand